# Service ID invalid when trying to use EmailJS with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, frontend

I created a form to contact me on my website, for that I use EmailJS.
However when I try to send myself a mail through the contact form I got a 400 Error `The service ID is invalid`.
I followed every steps of that tutorial as I haven't use EmailJS before `https://blog.mailtrap.io/react-send-email/`

Here is my Contact component

```
    class Contact extends React.Component {
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { feedback: '', name: 'Name', email: 'email@example.com' };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }
    
        render() {
          return (
            <form className="test-mailing">
              <h1>Let's see if it works</h1>
              <div>
                <textarea
                  id="test-mailing"
                  name="test-mailing"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              placeholder="Post some lorem ipsum here"
              required
              value={this.state.feedback}
              style={{width: '100%', height: '150px'}}
            />
          </div>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" className="btn btn--submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
        </form>
      )
      }

      handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({feedback: event.target.value})
      }
    
      handleSubmit() {
        const templateId = 'template_id';

          this.sendFeedback(templateId, {message_html: this.state.feedback, from_name: this.state.name, reply_to: this.state.email})
      }

      sendFeedback (templateId, variables) {
        window.emailjs.send(
          'gmail', templateId,
          variables
          ).then(res => {
            console.log('Email successfully sent!')
          })
          // Handle errors here however you like, or use a React error boundary
          .catch(err => console.error('Oh well, you failed. Here some thoughts on the error that occured:', err))
        }
}
```

And here is what I added in my `index.html`

```
`<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2.3.2/dist/email.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
        emailjs.init("my_user_ID_here"); // Obtain your user ID at the dashboard https://dashboard.emailjs.com/integration
      })();
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was happening to me, and it was because I didn't have the account activated.
when you log in, click on 'email services' and select, for example, gmail with your account

pd: google translate

Answer (score 4):

To fix this, I had to swap out `'gmail'` with my service ID.

```
sendFeedback (templateId, variables) {
        window.emailjs.send(
          ***serviceID here***, templateId,
          variables
          ).then(res => {
            console.log('Email successfully sent!')
          })
          // Handle errors here however you like, or use a React error boundary
          .catch(err => console.error('Oh well, you failed. Here some thoughts on the error that occured:', err))
        }
```

The JavaScript console in my web browser helped identify this.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.
To fix it,

> I had to paste NOT the 'gmail' string itself but the service_id which
> is below the icon gmail

in the EmailJS website after log in. Everyone has its own specific number. Also the template_id is important to put the id generated for your template.

When you want to publish your project it is advisable to place your special ids to the .env file to stay secure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check whether you are using the right integration id, check the id token you are using with the one under integration id on the dashboard, this was my issue

Answer (score 0):

Might as well share a quick fix that would probably save someone's time. I just had the same issue while using the code below.

```js
const notifyOwnerOfGuest = async () => {
  const userId = 'user_...';
  const serviceId = 'service_...';
  const templateId = 'template_...';
  const accessToken = 'e2e1...';

  const postfields = {
    user_id: userId,
    service_id: serviceId,
    template_id: templateId,
    accessToken,
  };

  const response = await fetch('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(postfields),
    // should explicitly add the header content-type here
  });

  if (!response.ok) throw await response.text();
};
```

I just explicitly added a `Content-type` header like so

```js
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
```

and now it works.