# 400 The service ID is invalid emailJS

Tags: reactjs, html-email

I am currently using emailJS on a project and I am having difficulties sending emails. Every time I try to send an email, the task fails both in the app and in the emailJS dashboard.

**The error inside of my dashboard is producing:**
400 The service ID is invalid. To find this ID, visit https://dashboard.emailjs.com/admin

**My console is producing:**
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 ()

**According the emailJS DOCS, the syntax should be:**

```
emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, templateParams, publicKey);
```

My ServiceID and templateID are correct as they have been copied and pasted.

I have tried searching for other forms of syntax but I have not found any. Any thought on how I could solve this? Thank you for your feedback.

**A similar StackOverflow question:**
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819127/service-id-invalid-when-trying-to-use-emailjs-with-react) was very similar, and I changed my ServiceID to fit the Syntax it suggested, however, I still have the same issue.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import emailJs from '@emailjs/browser'

const Contact = () => {
    const form = useRef()

    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        emailJs.sendForm(
            'service_gqp7he5',
            'template_6ufyan1',
            form.current,
            'C1NQS6PIhSTNngfAj'
        )
        .then (() => {
            alert('Message Successfully Sent')
        },
        () => {
            alert('Failed to send the message, please try again!')
            console.log();
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
        }, 3000)
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div className='container contact-page' >
                <div className='text-zone' >
                    <div className='contact-form'>
                        <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} >
                            <ul>
                                <li className='half'>
                                    <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name' required />
                                </li>

                                <li className='half'>
                                    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='youremail@email.com' required />
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type='text' name='subject' placeholder='Subject' required />
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <textarea placeholder='Message' name='message' required ></textarea>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <input type='submit' className='flat-button' value='SEND' />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Contact
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@emailjs/browser@3/dist/email.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
        emailjs.init("C1NQS6PIhSTNngfAj");
      })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service ID invalid when trying to use EmailJS with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819127/service-id-invalid-when-trying-to-use-emailjs-with-react)

Comment: @AhmedsSbai unfortunately it does not. I saw this post earlier today, and I did insert the ServiceID as instructed, but I am still running into the error. They are using vanilla JS as well vs. my React. I would imagine it wouldn't be a difference though.